# Don't understand why alert gives me correct result, while function doesn't execute javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three buttons. The idea is to change text on button id #11 and #12 when #1 is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dict = {#1: ['#11', '#12']}

    $('button').click(function () {
        var k = dict['#'+$(this).attr('id')]

        for (c in k){
            var m = k[c]
            $(m).button('it works')
        }
    })
});
```

Now the problem is: if I call `alert(m)`, I get the correct result, but it just doesn't work with `$(m).button('it works')`. Any idea why?

Comment: What do you want `$(m).button('it works')` to do? Button is not a jQuery function.

Comment: as far as my childhood could remember, .button is not a standard prototype. You probably wanted `.text` instead. Also, you are using a for...in with an **array**, which is not really whay you want (for..in is suitable for **object**, despite it **will work**). Here is a working fiddle for you case anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/gLnfo2h8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample HTML related to your code:

```
<button id="1">
  Ohay
</button>

<button id="11">
  hehe
</button>

<button id="12">
  haha
</button>
```

Correct javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dict = {'#1': ['#11', '#12']}

  $('button').click(function () {
      var k = dict['#'+$(this).attr('id')]
      for (c = 0; c < k.length; c++){
          var m = k[c]
          $(m).text('it works')
      }
  })
});
```

the **.button** prototype, as far as I know, is not a standard jQuery prototype, hence I probably suspect you wanted to use **.text** instead.

Besides, please be aware that you should change your **for..in** cycle with a  regular for instead (because you are looping an **array**, not an **object**), **despite it will work in that specific case** check this for reference: [why shouldn't I use for..in with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gLnfo2h8/

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(m).text('it works')`, `.button()` is not a jQuery function

Answer (score 1):

If `m` is a `button` target then all you need is to set it's `value`

```
jQuery has no function called button. the right solution would be:
$(m).text('some text')
```

if the button is actually an `<input type='button'` so you might need to do the following instead:

```
$(m).val('some text')
```

Solution would be like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dict = {#1: ['#11', '#12']}

$('button').click(function () {
    var k = dict['#'+$(this).attr('id')]

    for (c in k){
        var m = k[c]
        $(m).val('it works')
    }
})
});
```